# Java Unable to return variables

Tags: java

The code is fine, but when I need to take the variables out of the functions and put them into the public static void, it says the variable cannot be found. Anybody know how to solve this issue?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Greetings {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Greetings, " + String(s) + ". " +
            String(j) +"!" + " You are about " + int(z) + " years old");
    }
    public static String fNameGenerator(String s){
        Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter your first name: ");
        String first = scan1.next();
        s = first.substring(0,1).toUpperCase();
        return s;
    }
    public static String LastName(String j){
            Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Please enter you last name: ");
            String second = scan2.next();
            int x = second.length();
            String y = second.substring(0, x).toLowerCase();
            j = y.substring(0,1).toUpperCase();
            return j;
    }
    public static int age(int z){
        Scanner scan3 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter your year of birth: ");
          int third = scan3.nextInt();        
            z = (2015 - third);
            return z;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? A `void` method (e.g. `main()`) by definition cannot `return` anything.

Comment: Have a look at [Returning a Value from a Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html). Basically you need to declare local variables within `main()`, remove the input arguments from the other methods (as they're redundant) and then use the variables inside `System.out(..)`. E.g: `String fName = fNameGenerator();` `public static String fNameGenerator(){ /*...*/ return y.substring(0,1).toUpperCase();}` `System.out.println("Greetings, " + fName /*...*/);`.

Comment: Better formatting of source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not calling any of the methods, so how do you expect them to return something?

Two things to remember:

1. just because you wrote `return s` at the end of a method, it does not mean you can access `s` outside of this method. There's something called scopes in java, that means that a variable exists only on the scope it's define in- in your case - inside the methods. if you want it to exist outside - take the returned value and do something with it.
2. declaring the methods does nothing until you actually call them

so in order to access these variables, you need to do something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String s = fNameGenerator();
  String j = LastName();
  int z = age();
  System.out.println("Greetings, " + s + ". " + j +"!" +" You are about " + z + " years old");
}
```

one more thing you can see that I did there- you don't need to pass anything to your methods, as you are not doing anything with the given values before re-setting them. just make sure you declare the fields inside. for example your age method should look like:

```
public static int age(){
    Scanner scan3 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter your year of birth: ");
      int third = scan3.nextInt();        
        int z = (2015 - third);
        return z;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a compile error in your code

```
System.out.println("Greetings, " + String(s) + ". " + String(j) +"!" +" You are about " + int(z) + " years old");
```

If you're trying to call the methods then replace

```
String(s) --> fNameGenerator(s)
String(j) --> LastName(j)
int(z) --> age(z)
```

Have the s,j,z as the local variables or static members.

or remove the arguments passing to the method as you're getting input from scanner